# cURL How it work in case sentence Exclamation mark over 2ea

Tags: curl, factorial

I'm software engineer in korea

I have question below

It seems to apply factorial.

case ! mark over 2ea is error

curl -d "sentences=강추!!!!!" -X POST http://127.0.0.1:xxxxx/bertEmotionClassification

print below

sentences==============>...('sentences', '강추curl -d sentences=강추curl'), ('sentences', '강추curl -d sentences=강추curl'), ('sentences', '강추curl -d sentences=강추curl')....

below case OK( ! mark is one.)

curl -d "sentences=강추!" -X POST http://127.0.0.1:xxxxx/bertEmotionClassification

print below

sentences==============> ['강추!']

I think It was operation  with curl.
How I fix it?

This is occured in curl so I don't need modify in python
How I do that?

I want same curl input data and save to variable data.

curl = save variable data

Best recommend! = Best recommend!

Best recommend!!!!! = Best recommend!!!!!

Comment: Does this help? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33339/cant-use-exclamation-mark-in-bash

Comment: I saw url but  not fixed it